# showing data based on <select> option

Tags: php, jquery

I have .json file it contains the currencies of some countries

I'm retrieving  JSON data  from my file currencies.json to put it on a select>option form

I used foreach

my code :

```
 $string = file_get_contents("currencies.json");
 $black_a = json_decode($string, true);
    <?php  foreach ($black_a as $name => $black_p) {

 ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $black_p['name'];?>"><?php echo $black_p['name'];?></option>
```

example of My JSON file output :

```
{
    "symbol": "$",
    "name": "US Dollar",
    "symbol_native": "$",
    "decimal_digits": 2,
    "rounding": 0,
    "code": "USD",
    "name_plural": "US dollars"
},
```

so the thing is When user select a country from the list I want the symbol_native match with the selected country

```
<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                        <input type="number" value="1" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="form-control currency" >

                        <span class="input-group-addon"  style="margin-top: 10%;margin-left: -5;margin-right: 15%;">**`symbol_native Here`**</span>
                      </div>
```

Any idea how I can make this happen?

Comment: inside your foreach block, just add a `selected` attribute according to user selection, if the selection is available in get variable or post, then use it with an `if`

Comment: It's basic JavaScript, just use `symbol_native` as the `value` for each `<option>` and then get the selected value using the `onchange` event (for example, `<select onchange="selectCurrency(this.value)">`). The `selectCurrency(symbol)` simply uses the `symbol` variable passed to place it wherever you want. So give your `<span>` any id of your choice and use `.innerHTML` on that DOM object to print the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `onchange` listener on the `select` currency element :

```
<select id="natSelect" onchange="let csymbol = $(this).find(':selected').data('symbol');$('#natCurrency').text(csymbol)">
```

Make adjustment to each `option` item :

```
<option value="<?php echo $black_p['name'];?>" data-symbol="<?php echo $black_p['symbol'] ?>"><?php echo $black_p['name'];?></option>
```

And add `id` to the `span` currency symbol element :

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="natCurrency" style="margin-top: 10%;margin-left: -5;margin-right: 15%;">**`symbol_native Here`**</span>
```

Edit :

To show a default currency symbol, insert this code to the javascript block :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#natCurrency').text($('#natSelect').find(':selected').data('symbol'));
</script>
```

Comment: thanks it really helped, but it doesn't  show me the symbol for the default selected country
[img1](http://prntscr.com/ii3uif)

[img2](http://prntscr.com/ii3ue8)

Comment: To set a predefined or default currency, you could modify the select : `<select id="natSelect" ...` and insert this code on your javascript block : `<script type="text/javascript">$('#natCurrency').text($('#natSelect').find(':selected').data('symbol'));</script>`